# Inputting values into an existing table within MS Word

Tags: c#, ms-word

The purpose of my program is to make a copy of a template Word doc which contains a table within it and input text data into the cells of said table. My problem is that whenever I run the program it doesn't input any Text into the cells, I've searched online and as far as I'm aware there shouldn't be anything wrong with how I am inputting the text into the cells.

Here is the relevant code.

```
try
{
  //create filepaths for template and the soon to be created file
  object oMissing = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
  object notReadOnly = false;
  object oldDocPath = (object)@"Desktop:\testDoc.docx";
  object newDocPath = (object)@"Desktop:\testDoc2.docx";

  //start up word doc
  Word.Application app = new Word.Application();

  //open template in word
  Word.Document oldDoc = app.Documents.Open(ref oldDocPath, 
  ref oMissing, ref notReadOnly, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing,
  ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing,
  ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing);

  //save template under new name to make a copy
  app.ActiveDocument.SaveAs2(ref newDocPath, 
  ref oMissing, ref notReadOnly, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing,
  ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing,
  ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing);

  //close template and open the new document
  object doNotSaveChanges = Word.WdSaveOptions.wdDoNotSaveChanges;
  ((_Document)oldDoc).Close(ref doNotSaveChanges, ref oMissing, ref oMissing);
  Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(oldDoc);
  ((_Application)app).Quit(ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing);
  Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(app);
  Word._Application oWord;
  Word._Document oDoc;
  oWord = new Word.Application();
  oDoc = oWord.Documents.Add(ref newDocPath, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing);

  //populate the table
  Word.Table tbl = oDoc.Tables[1];
  tbl.Cell(1,1).Range.Text = "Test";

  //Close the last Word doc
  ((_Document)oDoc).Close(ref doNotSaveChanges, ref oMissing, ref oMissing);
  Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(oDoc);
  ((_Application)oWord).Quit(ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing);
  Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(oWord);
}
catch( Exception ex )
{
  MessageBox.Show("Exception Caught: " + ex.Message);
}
```

Okay; best guess I have is that **tbl.Cell(1,1).Range.Text = "Test";** probably isn't integrating properly with the way I've set out the rest of my code so any help would be appriciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some observations:

- If you specify wdDoNotSaveChanges when you close, you will not see
  "Test" in the saved document. You should see it in the open document
  immediately before you close, if the open document is being displayed
  (you may need to make the Window and Application visible to check
  that).
- When you use .Add to add to the document collection, Word will treat
  the document (in this case testDoc2.docx as a template, and
  willcreate another new document that would need to be named before
  you save it to disk. So even if changes were being saved, they would
  not be to testDoc2.docx. If you want to open an document and work on
  it, use .Open instead of .Add

One other thing.

When you open your "template" and save it as a new document, you already really have the document and the application object you need to work with, i.e., unless you need to close and quit the existing app. for some reason.

Comment: I admittedly was supposed to save the changes and must have forgotten to change it. Thanks for your help I've made some changes based on your feedback and things seem to be working fine now.